# How to call an applet from main method of a different class?

Tags: java, user-interface, applet

Can we call applet from main method? If so please suggest me.

Comment: I think no. I tried do this, but id didn't work.

Comment: *"Can we call applet from main method?"*  I don't know about you, but I can.  *"If so please suggest me."*  I suggest you don't do that.  Do you have the applet source code?

Comment: Ya my requirement is that,i am having applet which has GUI as opened pdf document along with many options,such as signing the pdf,saving the pdf and many more,So to use that applet in standalone application i need to call that applet from main by passing some parameters to applet OR is it possible to call the applet using swing classes?